# issue using mmap to write to a file

Tags: file, memory, mmap

Hello i am trying to use mmap to write data to a txt file. The code compiles and runs without any error however when i deference the address returned by mmap to write data into the file it seems that the data is not actually being written into it because the txt file is empty when i view it. Does anyone know what might be wrong? I have shown the code below:

```
int main ()
{

int fd;
int* file_in_memory;
struct stat file_info;


FILE* fp = fopen("./datatest.txt","w+");
if (fp == NULL){
    printf("error opening file\n");
}

ftruncate(fileno(fp), 1024*1024); // initialize the file referenced by fp with a size of 8MB = 1024*1024

fd = fileno(fp); //convert the file pointer(fp) to a file descriptor so we can use it with mmap


if (fstat(fd,&file_info) == -1){
    printf("could not get file size\n");
}
printf("the file size is %ld\n", file_info.st_size);


file_in_memory = (int* )mmap(NULL,file_info.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if(file_in_memory == MAP_FAILED){
    printf("failed to map memory\n");
    return 0;
}


for (int k=0; k < 20; k++){
file_in_memory[k] = k;  
}


close(fd);

 return 0;

}
```

If you need any further info let me know, and thank you.

Comment: Works for me, on Ubuntu. How _exactly_ are you 'viewing' the file? Have you tried `od datatest.txt`?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i am running it on debian 10. I tried view it with 'cat' and 'more' however they both show the file to be empty. i tried od but the values it displays are not what should be in the file, its sort of random

Comment: I suspect that you're expecting the file to contain ASCII digits, but your code actually writes numbers in binary form.

Comment: In particular what you write are character _codes_ 0 to 19, interspersed with 0's. All of these, in fact all character codes below 32, are [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) which _do not display anything_. The numbers shown by the `od` utitility _are_ what your program wrote to to file, displayed in octal, even if they're not what you wanted. (You can get decimal with `od -d` or hexadecimal with `od -x`.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks, you are right, that displayed the values correctly. However, the output is like: 0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7  and so on. Why is there a zero before every number?

Comment: Actually there's a zero _after_ each number you wrote.; Though not required, on most systems today C compilers make `int` 4 bytes, and your machine is apparently little-endian. Because `od` was designed back in the 1970s, it displays _2_ bytes at a time. When you store `int` 0 as little endian it is really _bytes_ 0 0 0 0, `int` 1 is bytes 1 0 0 0, `int` 2 is bytes 2 0 0 0, etc; `od` displays the first four bytes as 000000 000000, then 1 0 as 000001 and 0 0 as 000000, then 2 0 as 000002 and 0 0 as 000000, etc. For `-d` the leading zeros on each bytepair are suppressed so they 'look' smaller

Comment: but aren't really; each one is still 2 bytes.